# awk to zero pad to string field of a csv file

Tags: shell, awk

I need 6th column of a csv file to be padded with zeroes but when I try with below command, it just replaces the actual value to 0000.

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{$6 = sprintf("%04d", $6); print}' $Input
```

Input:

> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","123","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","23","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","3","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","4123","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"

Output:

> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","0123","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","0023","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","0003","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
> "xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","4123","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"

Comment: That's because the first character of $6 is not a digit, so in a numerical context, awk gives it the value zero.

Comment: For parsing CSV with (GNU) awk, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` with a custom field separator `","`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\",\""} {$6 = sprintf("%04d", $6)} 1' file

"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","0123","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","0023","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","0003","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
"xx","x","xxxxxx","xxx","xx","4123","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some non-awk ways to do this:

bash v5.1 includes a CSV command that can be enabled:

```sh
BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=${BASH/bin/lib}
enable -f csv csv

while IFS= read -r line; do
  csv -a row "$line"
  printf -v "row[5]" '%04d' "${row[5]}"
  printf '"%s"\n' "${row[@]}" | paste -sd,
done < file
```

Ruby

```sh
ruby -rcsv -e '
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row|
    row[5] = row[5].rjust(4, "0")
    puts CSV.generate_line(row, force_quotes: true)
  }
' file
```

Perl with Text::CSV

```sh
perl -MText::CSV=csv -e '
  $input = csv(in => shift @ARGV);
  @padded = map {$_->[5] = sprintf "%04d", $_->[5]; $_} @$input;
  csv(in => \@padded, always_quote => 1)
' file
```